# Problem with formFields in SIGN IN form AWS AMPLIFY

Tags: aws-amplify

I am using Amplify for sign in and sign up users.
I want to have customised fields for email and password in SIGN IN part.

Before using formFields my sign in form looks like this

[image]

In my file like this:

```
<AmplifySignIn headerText="Anmelden" usernameAlias="email"slot="sign-in"
          submitButtonText="Einloggen"
          
          ></AmplifySignIn>
```

So when I change input fields according to documentation using `formFields` like this

```
 <AmplifySignIn headerText="Anmelden" usernameAlias="email"slot="sign-in"
          submitButtonText="Einloggen"
          formFields={[
            {
              type: "email",
              label: "Custom email Label",
              placeholder: "custom email placeholder",
              required: true,
            },
            {
              type: "password",
              label: "Custom Password Label",
              placeholder: "custom password placeholder",
              required: true,
            },
          ]} 
          
          ></AmplifySignIn>
```

**The part Forgot your password is gone (look at image)**

[image]

Anyone has idea how to customise your fields but with **keeping Forgot your password option**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been addressed and may no longer be a problem. See:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/6479

Answer (score -1):

The AWS Amplify Authentication modules provide Authentication APIs and building blocks for developers who want to create apps with real-world production-ready user authentication.

With Amplify you can incorporate username / password based authentication as well as OAuth with Facebook, Google or Amazon.

You can find all the information by following this [blog post.](https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-user-authentication-with-the-amplify-framework-2inh)

And the code at this repo [here](https://github.com/dabit3/amplify-auth-demo/blob/master/src/Form.js) (thanks Nader!).

Comment: Does not answer the question; this seems like a generic response. I am struggling with weird issues coming from customized form fields myself (the authenticator seems to "forget" the value of the form field, even though the text is present in the box), and would appreciate more accurate information on the `formFields` prop usage, mentioned on neither of these pages.